# Is echo checking normally used in any modern systems?

Tags: networking, error-checking

I know that *echo checking* is not considered as a good mechanism. However, I want to know whether are systems even today which use it?

Edit:

Actually, this was a part of my homework but I couldn't find much resources online on this so asking here.

Comment: Good mechanism for what? Echo checking of what?

Comment: Good mechanism for error detection. Echo checking of data sent over the network.

Comment: So who said it wasn't considered as a good mechanism? It's always the first transaction I build in any system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminals often use local echo, but remote echo can be turned on and is in this sense echo checking. Check out this paper on telnet:

Telnet and the Telnet Protocol (IBM Corporation White Paper)
http://bandwidthco.com./whitepapers/netforensics/telnet/Telnet%20and%20the%20Telnet%20Protocol.pdf